# Vue.js - Div - use string result from computed as class name

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I might be into deep water here - trying to make a css-grid work in IE11 and Vue.js

I have a LI like this:

```
  <li :class="{getClass}">
  </li>
```

getClass is a computed method:

```
getClass: function () {
  return "Row" + this.getMSRow() + "Column" + this.getMSColumn();
},
```

And in the stylesheet I have the def. of all the classes:

```
.Row1Column1 {
   -ms-grid-column: 1;
   -ms-grid-row: 1;
   grid-column: 1;
   grid-row: 1;
}
```

This actually works very fine in IE11.

My issue is the fact that I need to add 2 more conditional classes to the same LI.

```
 :class="{
  getClass,
  'calendar-day--not-current': !day.isCurrentMonth,
  'calendar-day--today': isToday,
}"
```

This doesn't work - it makes 'getClass' a class - instead of the result of the computed method. I assume it's just a matter of some simple syntax..., but I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you know that IE11 supports only initial version of CSS Grid and that means it does not support many CSS Grid features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to define a computed class object in order to use it directly in `:class` binding:

```
<li :class="liClass">
</li>
...

computed: {
   liClass () {
     return {
      [this.getClass]: true,
      'calendar-day--not-current': !this.day.isCurrentMonth,
      'calendar-day--today': this.isToday,
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anatoly - it worked - just remove the paranthesis from the call to getClass - as it is a computed.

computed: {
   liClass () {
     return {
      [this.getClass]: true,
      'calendar-day--not-current': !this.day.isCurrentMonth,
      'calendar-day--today': this.isToday,
     }
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
: class="[
    getClass,
    { 'calendar-day--not-current': !day.isCurrentMonth },
    { 'calendar-day--today': isToday },
]"
```

if you want to have static class as well.

```
: class="[
    'static-class',
    getClass,
    { 'calendar-day--not-current': !day.isCurrentMonth },
    { 'calendar-day--today': isToday },
]"
```